# Cross Join on a subset of 2 tables

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to copy data from an old database design to a new database design.

The database is for a multi-tenancy application, and the source table in question is a table of widget category names.

Each tenant has their own private set of category names, so the old table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE OldCategories (
    TenantId     bigint,
    CategoryName nvarchar(255)
)

OldCategories:
TenantId, CategoryName
       1, 'Dog Toys'
       1, 'Cat Toys'
       1, 'Lizard Toys',
       2, 'Dog Toys'
       2, 'Duck Toys'
```

The new database adds an intermediate table such that all of a tenant's categories must be duplicated for each row in the intermediate table, here is the new schema:

```
CREATE TABLE NewCategoryGroups (
    TenantId  bigint,
    GroupId   bigint IDENTITY,
    GroupName nvarchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE NewCategories (
    GroupId      bigint,
    CategoryName nvarchar(255)
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ( GroupId, CategoryName )
)
```

Here's what's in the NewCategoryGroups table:

```
NewCategoryGroups:
TenantId, GroupId, GroupName
       1,       1, '2006 Toys'
       1,       2, '2010 Toys'
       1,       3, '2016 Toys'
       2,       4, '2007 Toys'
       2,       5, '2010 Toys'
```

And here is the example data I want to get for the NewCategories table:

```
NewCategories 
GroupId, CategoryName
      1, 'Dog Toys' -- Groups 1 through 3 are for Tenant 1
      1, 'Cat Toys'
      1, 'Lizard Toys',
      2, 'Dog Toys'
      2, 'Cat Toys'
      2, 'Lizard Toys',
      3, 'Dog Toys'
      3, 'Cat Toys'
      3, 'Lizard Toys',
      4, 'Dog Toys' -- Groups 4 and 5 are for Tenant 2
      4, 'Duck Toys'
      5, 'Dog Toys'
      5, 'Duck Toys'
```

I've tried a `CROSS JOIN`, as-in:

```
SELECT
    CategoryName
FROM
    OldCategories
    CROSS JOIN NewCategoryGroups
```

...except this loses the TenantId distinction, so every tenant will get every other tenant's categories.

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: @FelixPamittan I have updated my question

Comment: Your database design is not good, you should have primary key for each table. Why NewCategories having duplicate CategoryName ?

Comment: @RajavelD `NewCategories` has a composite-key, and CategoryName is duplicate because it represents a different category, even if they share the same name - this is a denormalization - if I were to normalize it away it would add another FK lookup and increased maintenance burden for no performance gain (as category-names are not shared between categories as far as business-rules are concerned).

Comment: Ok What is your expected output ? Do u want to insert old date to new tables ? If so how will you populate GroupId, GroupName ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use an `INNER JOIN` instead

```
SELECT
    g.GroupId,
    c.CategoryName
FROM OldCategories c
INNER JOIN NewCategoryGroups g
    ON g.TenantId = c.TenantId
```